# Is the sentence $(x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1$ open or closed?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Is the sentence $(x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1$ open or closed? Why?

My textbook says a sentence is open if its truth value depends on some of its variables. However, in this case, I see that it doesn't depend on the value of $x$ because the statement applies for all $x$ therefore it's a closed sentence.

By the way, the answer in my book says it's an open sentence.

Comment: Can you cite your book? This is indeed an open sentence. Even better: cite textually (copy paste and provide authorship details)

Comment: A statement such as $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$, whose truth value depends on the values of certain variables, is called open. (translated from swedish).

Comment: What if $x$ is not real number but mathematical object such that $(x+1)^2$ is not always equal $x^2+2x+1$. Is there some indication that $x$ is integer, real or complex number?

Comment: You're right it's open, note however that $\forall x [(x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1]$ is closed and true in the rationals, reals, or complex numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your textbook is informally mostly correct, but a bit sloppy and/or misleading, if you've quoted it exactly. A sentence is *open* iff it has at least one free variable. This is purely a syntactic property, not a semantic one; you have correctly observed that the semantic value of $(x+1)^2 = x^2 + 2x + 1$ is always "true" whenever $x$ is instantiated and the symbols endowed with their usual "ring" meanings, but that's not relevant to determining whether the sentence is open.

Comment: You do not need commutativity whatsoever for this to be true in any ring

Comment: I think that what you have in mind is that $$(x+a)^2$$ is not in general equal to $$x^2+ 2ax + a^2$$ whenever $a\neq1$ or the ring is non-commutative.

Comment: Fair enough, I just hedged at the time because I couldn't be bothered to think!